# Merge two dataset with identical columns'name

Tags: merge, sas

I have the below data set `A` and `B`, both share the same variable (column) `ID`.

[image]

If I perform a `merge` like below.

```
data C ;
 merge A B ;
 by ID ;
run ;
```

SAS will get data set `B`'s columns' value if both name are identical (except for the `ID` column).

[image]

Is there any documentation explains this behavior (like how does SAS decide to get the value from which dataset since they both exist in 2 datasets)? I tried reading [SAS's documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/a000202970.htm)  but haven't found anything explains this.

Comment: And what do you want to get? Did you try `update` statement?

Comment: Merge is truly one of SAS's hard to get thing for a beginner. Did you try this: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001304305.htm

Comment: BTW in your case it's straightforward. A dataset to the right overwrites columns of datasets to the left. That's the expected behavior

Comment: @SanekZhitnik Thanks for the comment, but I didn't ask about what I want to get. What I want to know is how SAS decided to get which value, is there any official documentation explains that?

Comment: @PythonRSAS thanks for always being helpful, can you give me a link which explains more about `A dataset to the right overwrites columns of datasets to the left.` ?

Comment: There are some SUGI papers that can be useful. "Merge with Caution: How to Avoid Common Problems when Combining SAS® Datasets " and "SAS® DATA  Step  Merge  –  A  Powerful  Tool"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chapter 4 of the SAS Language reference explains the process in section ["DATA Step Processing during Match-Merging"](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1tgk0uanvisvon1r26lc036k0w7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p06o0a09ikoqmzn1vbteq7mwrdca). *My bold*.

> #### DATA Step Processing during a One-to-One Reading
>
> - Compilation phase
>
>   - SAS reads the descriptor information of each data set named in the SET statement and then creates a program data vector that contains all the variables from all data sets as well as variables created by the DATA step.
> - Execution — Step 1
>
>   - When SAS executes the first SET statement, SAS reads the first observation from the first data set into the program data vector. The second SET statement reads the first observation from the second data set into the program data vector. **If both data sets contain the same variables, the values from the second data set replace the values from the first data set, even if the value is missing.** After reading the first observation from the last data set and executing any other statements in the DATA step, SAS writes the contents of the program data vector to the new data set. The SET statement does not reset the values in the program data vector to missing, except for those variables that were created or assigned values during the DATA step.
> - Execution — Step 2
>
>   - SAS continues reading from one data set and then the other until it detects an end-of-file indicator in one of the data sets. SAS stops processing with the last observation of the shortest data set and does not read the remaining observations from the longer data set.

One important difference between `MERGE` and `UPDATE` statements is that in `UPDATE` **the values from the second data set replace the values from the first data set, ONLY if the value is NOT missing.**

The concept is extended when more than two data sets are listed:

- For a `MERGE` statement the outcome is that the rightmost, or last read, value of a variable is placed in the PDV
- For an `UPDATE` statement the outcome is that the rightmost, or last read, NON-MISSING value of a variable is placed in the PDV

NOTE: The `MODIFY` statement replaces values in-place in the master data set and does not write output data sets anew, as does `MERGE` and `UPDATE`.